# Is it possible to fix MBR without user interaction?

Tags: boot, mbr, bootable-media, dd

I have a case in which a virus spreaded through an intranet, and rewrote the MBR of 12.000 machines.

Now, I know how to manually repair an MBR, but I'm being asked to provide a solution to automate this process by creating a bootable USB media which would proceed to repair the MBR without user interaction.

This way, we could distribute several copies of this bootable image and speed up the repair of so many machines.

To my knowledge, all these machines have their bootable partition on /dev/sda1, but the sectors to repair should be identified using a pattern that is the virus footprint.

So, is it possible at all to execute, say, `dd` on boot, without any user interaction?

Comment: are the clients windows,linux, or mixed?  Since the MBR is zapped do they boot into windows or the OS?

Comment: to my knowledge, they are windows machines. it seems the ransomware didn't spread to linux machines. I don't understand the second part of your question. Are you asking if (after manually repairing the MBR) they are capable of booting into windows again?

Comment: No, I am asking right now in there broken MBR state do they boot into windows?

Comment: they don't boot at all. From what I'm reading, bootable usb sticks don't have access to execute commands as sudo...

Comment: PXE (pronounced pixie) booting is probably the closet thing your going ot get.

Comment: "bootable usb sticks can't get sudo" this is FALSE.  I just did it today. In fact I mounted the NTFS partition from linux and cleared all the windows passwords.

Comment: It sounds like they figured a way to do something similar last night

Comment: btw, the asumption about sudo came from a tutorial to build your own liveCD that said: this won't work if you try to add commands that need sudo before launching X. So I didn't try it. Perhaps any live cd iso could be manually modified to run such command by addint it to `/etc/rc.local`. I didn't get to try it bc another consultant came up with a working solution using a bootable stick. I don't know what procedure he used

Answer (score 1):

If they don't boot at all:

Setup PXE boot to boot a custom ISO with linux and the MBR on it.
Have it automatically rewrite the MBR and reboot.

Here is an 11/16MB distro you can add your MBR and dd to.

http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/downloads.html

You will want this to help setup your bootable linux OS
https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/

Windows PE ISO is also a good option.

Add an entry to the DHCP server to aid in the process.
**Some computers to this as an auto fail over condition.** Then no user intervention would be needed.

The rest someone has to push F11 or etc to boot from the network.  The boot order in the bios could also changed to automatically fail to PXE boot.

[image]

Linux

edit dhcpd.conf

```
vi /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

and to add the following entries:

```
#option 66
option tftp-server-name "w.x.y.z";

#option 67
option bootfile-name "test.cfg";
```

Then to restart the DHCP Server.

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Also this link for more detailed instructions:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/tftpboot-server

Comment: I loved your proposed solution and this is something I will try in my home LAN. However, I'm told that this company doesn't have the intranet available. I don't know what part of the network depended of a layer of windows machines that also got infected. Why? beats me.

Comment: @amenadiel Unless all the computers have static IP there is a DHCP server somewhere.  Even if there isn't you can easily boot an ISO from a USB stick that contains a DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to run dd without interactions and you could use a Linux netboot with systemd services but its also a really bad idea to blindly provision that many servers.

Here's a better idea use a PXE payload to chainload the Windows bootloader and once your servers are up you can send them all the command to update their MBR from Windows with the `bootsect` command.

You can load GRUB over the network and give it a configuration that will load the OS. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Network

From your Linux server that will be used for PXE serving (I suggest just creating a new VM for it):

Setup DHCP and TFTP for PXE.

`grub-mknetdir --net-directory=/srv/tftp --subdir=/boot/grub -d /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc`

`nano /srv/tftp/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and add:

```
search -s root -f /Boot/BCD
ntldr /bootmgr
boot
```

Systems should load grub then search for partitions containing a ntldr BCD then load the bootmgr.

Once you have your servers up you can read about how to fix the MBR here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options probably just `bootsect /nt60 SYS`

Comment: This assumes this virus didn't also get to Windows BCD. But it makes no assumptions about device, boot code, active partition code. It detects and goes straight to Windows boot manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this company intranet had its structure based in windows servers that also got infected. I proposed manually repairing a few of them to get some parts of the intranet working, but in the in-between another consultant made a bootable stick that kinda worked as asked. I agree, such bootable stick could potentially be used to unwittingly zero-fill a machine

Comment: @amenadiel More power to you on fixing that mess. But what I don't understand is if the machines are all infected with malware why aren't they just reprovisioning all the servers new?

Comment: I'm not positive about the servers being infected, as external consultants only get told so much. Perhaps the intranet was just temporarily shutdown for stop the malware from spreading further. We were only told the intranet was down as well and therefore no PXE. But now that you mention it, I'll give the heads up that if there are any windows servers involved, they should be reprovisioned. The infection vector, however, came from a person in the salesteam running an email attachment. Again, we're not positive about that fact, and probably won't be informed further